# How to make SVG viewBox respect size of an element where width/height are given in precentage?

Tags: svg

I have created a simple SVG image where one of the element's width/height are given in percentage.

```
<svg width="200" height="100" viewBox="0,0,200,100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="teal"></rect>
    <circle r="50" cx="100" cy="50" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>
```

**Issue**

When I change the viewBox to scale/move the view to only show the top right part of the SVG image, the element with the width/height specified in percentage is no longer visible.

For example:

```
<svg width="200" height="100" viewBox="100,0,100,50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="teal"></rect>
    <circle r="50" cx="100" cy="50" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>
```

See this CodePen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XqYjqW

Comment: Change the rect not to use percentages.

Comment: @RobertLongson What if I do need to express the width/height of an element in percentage?

Comment: Then you probably shouldn't be using a viewBox.